# Shortcut keys - Windows key function and some other shortcuts - Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, remote-desktop

I'm new to Linux and have been using Kubuntu for the past 2 weeks - absolutely love it!

I've found though that the shortcut keys aren't always working as expect. For instance, when I am in a fullscreen Xfreerdp session to Windows RDP and I press the Windows button, Plasma's full screen app launcher overlays the RDP session.

I would expect the Windows start key to not be captured locally but only in the RDP session. Is there a way to fix that?
My XfreeRDP command looks like this:

```
xfreerdp /multimon /u:xxx /v:xxx /audio-mode:0 /mic +clipboard +fonts -wallpaper /printer -decorations +auto-reconnect /auto-reconnect-max-retries:10
```

KDE Plasma 5.19.5
Kubuntu 20.10

Comment: This might be a [bug with Wayland](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1704870), but Ubuntu have their own version of xfreerdp called `remmina` which has an [option to passthrough the Windows key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57725/remmina-doesnt-eat-keys). You might also try pressing right-ctrl which is sometimes mapped to win-key. The [documentation](https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/User/FreeRDP-User-Manual.markdown) suggests that you may also need to set the particular keyboard and mapping you're using eg `/kbd:US`.